# What is the command that gives a diamond sword 1 heart of damage instead of the regular?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can anyone tell me what the command is? I want to troll my friends on the computer but I have no idea what it is. Also, this would help out other people because barely anyone knows it even exists!

Answer (score 3):

This is the command to give a diamond sword that does 1 heart of damage:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUIDMost:97164,UUIDLeast:107213}]}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't damage measured usually in half of hearts?

Comment: @ModDL This should do 1/2 a heart on top of the base 1/2 heart attack damage, so 1 heart total (though it could be said that the diamond sword itself is only doing 1/2 a heart of the damage, your fist the rest).

Comment: Right, item damage is measured in +X Attack Damage, not straight up Attack Damage